# Query posts only if meta_value is not empty

Tags: meta-query

Can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm trying to query posts for a member mailing list and simply don't want to include users that are not members. Right now even the users that have an empty meta_value to the meta_key 'member' are shown. Please help! (WP version 5.3.2)

```
    function get_all_users () {


        $args = array( 
            'orderby' => 'display_name',
            'meta_query' => array (
    array (

            'key' => 'member',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
      )
    );

$users = get_users($args);

        ob_start();

// Array of WP_User objects.
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {

            $firstName = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'first_name', true);
            $lastName = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', true);
            echo "<li><a href=\"mailto:" . $user->user_email . "\">" . $firstName . " " . $lastName . "</a></li>";
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Comment: You define `get_all_users` but call `get_users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this worked. Notice that there is a space in the meta_value.

```
$args = array( 
        'orderby' => 'display_name',
        'meta_key' => 'member',
        'meta_value' => ' ',
        'meta_compare' => '!='
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing they value from your meta query:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'display_name',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'member',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
    ),
);

$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, can you verify that ´member´ is set for the users? The query seems correct.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I finally managed to figure it out :)